# Why does numpy not raise an error when inverting a singular matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-inverse

I am writing a tutorial, as part of which I wanted to show some of the issues that occur when analyzing data that has a singular covariance matrix.

I came across some odd behavior in numpy.

The behavior in question is this:

1. Given a singular matrix (A) np.linalg.inv(A) will execute without raising an exception
2. The function returns a matrix that is not an inverse of the original matrix A*inv(A) != I

My question is essentially: can anyone explain why this behavior is allowed, or is it a bug or am I misunderstanding something? I am not looking for solutions for how to get the inverse or approximate inverse of a singular matrix.

Moreover what method is numpy using to test for singularity? It appears that it is not checking the condition number alone (see below).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712734/numpy-possible-for-zero-determinant-matrix-to-be-inverted) seems to relate to the same behavior (at least point 1 above) however the accepted answer (that the OPs test that their matrix is singular in the first place is not working correctly owing to very small numbers in the covariance matrix does not apply in my case).

Below is a complete example demonstrating the issue. I am working in numpy 1.24.2 with Python 3.10. Any help is much appreciated.

#### Numpy inverts a singular matrix without error

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import ortho_group

def generate_random_cov_matrix(sz, rank, eig_val_scale):
    """
    Generate a random covariance matrix with known rank by building it from a specified number of eigenvectors and eigenvalues

    :param sz: the returned covariance matrix with be shaped sz x sz
    :param rank: the desired rank of the returned matrix
    :param eig_val_scale: eigenvalues will be randomly sampled from a chi2 distribution (df=1) and scaled by this parameter
    :return: the covariance matrix

    """
    if rank > sz:
        raise ValueError('rank cannot be greater than size')

    #
    eig_vecs = ortho_group.rvs(dim=sz)
    eig_vecs = eig_vecs[:, 0:rank]
    # randomly sample eigenvalues from chi square (df=1) just so that  smaller eigenvalues are more likely
    eig_vals = np.random.chisquare(1, rank) * eig_val_scale
    # sort in descending order
    eig_vals = np.sort(eig_vals)
    eig_vals = eig_vals[::-1]
    # build matrix from eigenvectors and eigenvalues
    cov = eig_vecs @ np.diag(eig_vals) @ eig_vecs.T
    return cov, eig_vecs, eig_vals


# generate a singular 20 x 20 covariance matrix
n_variables = 20
rank = 10
cov_mat,_,_ = generate_random_cov_matrix(n_variables,rank,100)

# is it singular as expected
assert np.isclose(np.linalg.det(cov_mat),[0.])

# are the elements of the of the covariance matrix so small that their determinant could be >0 but zero due to machine precision
print(np.mean(cov_mat))


# does numpy compute its inverse without an exception
try:
    cov_inv = np.linalg.inv(cov_mat)
    print('No exception was raised')
except:
    print('An exception was raised')


# is the resulting inverse a proper inverse (is A*inv(A) equal to an identity matrix)

try:
    assert np.isclose(cov_mat @ cov_inv,np.identity(n_variables))
except AssertionError:
    print('The computed inverse is not a proper inverse')
```

#### Numpy doesn't check the condition number alone

```py
# runs without failure
arr = np.array([[1.0, 1.2], [2.0 + 1e-14, 2.4 + 1e-14]])
rank = np.linalg.matrix_rank(arr)
cond = np.linalg.cond(arr)
np.linalg.inv(arr)
print("rank: ", rank)
print("cond: ", cond)

# fails despite having the same condition number
arr = np.array([[1.0, 1.2], [2.0 + 1e-15, 2.4 + 1e-15]])
rank = np.linalg.matrix_rank(arr)
np.testing.assert_approx_equal(cond, np.linalg.cond(arr))
cond = np.linalg.cond(arr)
print("rank: ", rank)
print("cond: ", cond)
np.linalg.inv(arr)
```

Comment: are you taking in to account floating point accuracy?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I believe so. I use np.isclose rather than testing for exact equality (e.g. between the identity matrix and the product of cov_mat and its inverse). Is this what you are asking?

Comment: if close to singular the `det` should be very small, and the inverse terms large and wildly inaccurate.

Comment: thanks @hpaulj. My question is rather shouldn't this situation raise an error in numpy? Why does numpy allow np.linalg.inv to execute without an error when the matrix is singular and return an inverse that is patently not an inverse. Is this a bug, a feature that I am not understanding the utility of, or am I missing something else?

Comment: I'm guessing that `numpy` is using a fairly standard library to calculate the inverse.  I don't know close to exactly singular it has to be to raise the error.

Comment: While `det` is small (`-1e-128`), the `inv` elements are all on the order of `e13`.  Evidently that's not close enough to trigger the singular error from the underlying compiled code.

Comment: AFAIK, safely checking if the matrix is singular is expensive (one way to do that is to use an expensive SVD which tends to be actually more expensive than computing the inverse). The main focus of Numpy is speed (at the expense of only few cheap checks). People should ensure a requested operation is valid on a given input. Scipy might provide a safer alternative (Scipy focus more on correctness and being safe, often at the expense of a significantly slower execution).